# Epoch time `date +%s` equivalent in python

Tags: python, bash, shell, date, epoch

I'm looking a simple way to show in python the bash command `date +%s` in a python. The command `date +%s` shows the epoch time.

Thanks

Comment: `import time; print(time.time())` should do

Comment: `print(int(time.time()))` more precisely.

Comment: if I wanted to make this a variable, it would go something like `distro_date = print(time.time())`?

Comment: @Amado `distro_date = int(time.time())` after having imported `time`.

Comment: `print` returns `None`.

Comment: I can print out with `print distro_date` after setting up the variable `distro_date = int(time.time())` after importing time, but the variable comes out empty when I use it in a  key pair ``distributed_on': distro_date`` even though it prints ok. any ideas?

Comment: @M.T any ideas why the variable to output anything but able to print out?